# C# namespace manager doesn't work parsing a XML with namespace

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xml-namespaces

I am trying to parse the XML from [this url](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml), sampled below, in C#:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gesmes:Envelope xmlns:gesmes="http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01"
                 xmlns="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref">
    <gesmes:subject>Reference rates</gesmes:subject>
    <gesmes:Sender>
        <gesmes:name>European Central Bank</gesmes:name>
    </gesmes:Sender>
    <Cube>
        <Cube time='2020-01-16'>
            <Cube currency='USD' rate='1.1169'/>
            <Cube currency='JPY' rate='122.80'/>
            <Cube currency='BGN' rate='1.9558'/>
        </Cube>
    </Cube>
</gesmes:Envelope>
```

This is the code I am using to get currencies:

```
xml.Load(@"https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml");
XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
ns.AddNamespace("gesmes", "http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref");

XmlNodeList nodes = xml.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/gesmes:Envelope/Cube/Cube/Cube", ns);
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
  // some code here
}
```

However, `nodes` is always `null`. I have tried a lot of options, and the unique option it worked for me was removing namespace from the original XML. But I would like to parse the source directly without modifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three issues to correct:

1. You misdefine the namespace associated with `gesmes`.

   Change

   ```
   ns.AddNamespace("gesmes", "http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref");
   ```

   to

   ```
   ns.AddNamespace("gesmes", "http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01");
   ```
2. Your XPath doesn't take into account that `Cube` and its descendants are in the default namespace.

   Create a prefix for the default namespace:

   ```
   ns.AddNamespace("eu", "http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref");
   ```
3. Update your XPath with the namespace prefix from #2:

   ```
   /gesmes:Envelope/eu:Cube/eu:Cube/eu:Cube
                    ^^^     ^^^     ^^^
   ```

   (`Cube` cubed?    )

After fixing the above issues, your code should work as expected.

Answer (score -1):

Linq XML has always given me less headaches:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml");
string ns = "http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref";

var outerCube = doc.Root.Element(XName.Get("Cube", ns));
var timeCube = outerCube.Element(XName.Get("Cube", ns));

Console.WriteLine("Time: " + timeCube.Attribute("time").Value);

foreach (var cube in timeCube.Elements())
{
    Console.WriteLine(cube.Attribute("currency").Value + " => " + cube.Attribute("rate"));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I just wrote the same code for somebody last month.  Use a dictionary

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string URL = "https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(URL);
            XNamespace ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();

            Dictionary<string, decimal> dict = doc.Descendants(ns + "Cube").Where(x => x.Attribute("currency") != null)
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Attribute("currency"), y => (decimal)y.Attribute("rate"))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
        }
    }


}
```